# Is there any other media that would continue from where Storm Hawks finished

Tags: storm-hawks

I saw the last episode of season 2 (Episode 52: Cyclonia Rising (Part 2)) a few years ago. Because of how it ended I was waiting for a season 3 however it doesn't seem as if one would be coming out since it's been this long.

I am also wondering, like Anime how most are adaptations of another media (like a manga in most cases or a light novel like with Kara no Kyoukai). I am wondering if there are any media that either continues off from where the cartoon finished or at least has a more conclusive end that what the cartoon series has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_Hawks#Comic_books) there are plans for a comic book series.